# Reference of a coloumn from a 2D Array Excel

Tags: excel

Good day, I have googled the life out of this and I am sure it is so simple. I am trying to find the reference in coloumn A (which are letters) after a 2D lookup in a table of random numbers. The 2D lookup is working fine but I have tried many formula's to get the reference letter in the first coloumn to no avail. ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Tried to re-create the table as I can't upload pics.

My formula is =VLOOKUP(E34,B4:M29,MATCH(E32,B2:M2))

I have built another formula =INDEX(A2:M29,MATCH(H34,B4:B29,0),MATCH(H32,B2:M2,0)) which I thought would work but returns the wrong value. I think I have to nest a INDEX in a INDEX?

Really not sure - please HELP!

Comment: `VLOOKUP` requires an *exact* match. And something as simple as a different format of the cell (text rather than number, say) could cause the look-up to fail. What is the relationship between E32 and E34?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Your question: the formula is working well but if you use `a comma as the last parameter` then it will find the Exact match. as you said your reference contains letters so the last parameter (just a comma) is not necessary here. Any way i have tried to draw a figure as you explained. And the Reference you are trying to get: it is not got by a formula, once you have supplied the reference then you can get the reference values using a `Data Validation List` option and choose correct letters. More over for which column do you want to retrieve the value for your reference? for this you can again use Data Validation List for Column Numbers (Names etc). The formula I used is: `=VLOOKUP(E34,B4:M29,MATCH(E32,B2:M2),)` in `E36`.

[image]

If this answer is not enough, then you should explain your question again in detail. Thanks.